# Python regex to parse semi-fixed width file

Tags: python, regex

I have a data file that is essentially a fixed-width text file.  There are a variable number of spaces and positioning in the text.  I'm trying to parse the file into a list with python and can't figure out the appropriate regex (of course am open to non-regex options too).

```
Date              Run    By           Level 1        Level 2        Level 3        Level 4        Level 5        Level 6        Level 7        Level 8        Level 9


11-15-2014 12:27:43 AM 1    **                          259.0                                                                                                         
11-15-2014 7:47:09 AM 1    **            98.0                                                                                                                        
11-15-2014 3:45:07 PM 1    **                                         785.0                                                                                          
11-16-2014 12:27:43 AM 1    **                          245.0                                                                                                         
11-16-2014 7:51:36 AM 1    **            96.0                                                                                                                        
11-16-2014 3:43:12 PM 1    **                                         788.0                                                                                          
11-17-2014 12:27:43 AM 1    **                          248.0                                                                                                         
11-17-2014 7:51:21 AM 1    **           104.0                                                                                                                        
11-17-2014 12:45:57 PM 1    **            97.0          257.0          793.0                                                                                          
11-17-2014 3:46:33 PM 1    **                                         792.0                                                                                          
11-18-2014 12:32:31 AM 1    **                          253.0                                                                                                         
11-18-2014 7:50:31 AM 1    **           104.0                                                                                                                        
11-18-2014 3:48:43 PM 1    **                                         781.0                                                                                          
11-19-2014 12:30:36 AM 1    **                          260.0                                                                                                         
11-19-2014 8:40:26 AM 1    **           102.0                                                                                                                        
11-19-2014 3:47:45 PM 1    **                                         803.0                                                                                          
11-20-2014 12:28:40 AM 1    **                          243.0                                                                                                         
11-20-2014 7:53:38 AM 1    **           107.0                                                                                                                        
11-20-2014 3:43:55 PM 1    **                                         787.0                                                                                          
11-21-2014 1:03:45 AM 0    PS                          245.0                                                                                                         
11-21-2014 7:52:55 AM 1    **           101.0                                                                                                                        
11-21-2014 3:44:09 PM 1    **                                         789.0                                                                                          
11-22-2014 12:37:26 AM 1    **                          250.0                                                                                                         
11-22-2014 7:49:55 AM 1    **           103.0
```

Thus far I've tried:

```
for line in f:
    line = re.split(r' (?=[A-Z])| (?=[0-9])|            ',line)
```

However, I don't get even alignment of the columns.  I need them to line up for use downstream.

The desired output is (sorry for the limited number of rows, parsing it manually is deadly!).

```
['Date', '', 'Run', 'By', 'Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4', 'Level 5', 'Level 6', 'Level 7', 'Level 8', 'Level 9','\r\n']
['\r\n']
['\r\n']
['11-15-2014', '12:27:43', 'AM 1', '**', '', '259.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '\r\n']
['11-15-2014',  '7:47:09', 'AM 1', '**', '98.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '\r\n']
['11-15-2014',  '3:45:07', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '785.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '\r\n']
...
...
['11-17-2014', '12:45:57', 'PM 1',  '**', '97.0', '257.0', '793.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '\r\n']
```

In essence 13 items followed by a line break; combining date and time into a single field would be fine, mostly I need the dates and three levels to line up properly; there are only values for Level 1, Level 2, and Level 3.  Values are usually a single level/row, but occasionally there are all three (as shown).

Comment: what is d expected output

Comment: I strongly recommend changing that file's layout, if possible. It's a mess, and splitting/parsing it will inevitably be hacky.

Comment: whats the logic behind your splitting ? show a desire output

Comment: Are there any tabs in the file? It looks like it's tab separated.

Comment: OP confirms these are spaces. The **right** answer is change file format to some standard format. But I'm sure some hacks are coming our way :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's output from proprietary software; I can't change the upstream format.  Agreed that this is a hack.  I've gone as far as using fixed delimiting in spreadsheet software, but the variable spacing doesn't facilitate even that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the only part that has variable width is the date/time. I would suggest this:

```
m = re.match(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+) (.{4})(.{6})(.{16})(.{15})(.{15})', line)
if m:
    print [x.strip() for x in m.groups()]
```

Output:

```
['11-15-2014 12:27:43', 'AM 1', '**', '', '259.0', '']
['11-15-2014 7:47:09', 'AM 1', '**', '98.0', '', '']
['11-15-2014 3:45:07', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '785.0']
['11-16-2014 12:27:43', 'AM 1', '**', '', '245.0', '']
['11-16-2014 7:51:36', 'AM 1', '**', '96.0', '', '']
['11-16-2014 3:43:12', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '788.0']
['11-17-2014 12:27:43', 'AM 1', '**', '', '248.0', '']
['11-17-2014 7:51:21', 'AM 1', '**', '104.0', '', '']
['11-17-2014 12:45:57', 'PM 1', '**', '97.0', '257.0', '793.0']
['11-17-2014 3:46:33', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '792.0']
['11-18-2014 12:32:31', 'AM 1', '**', '', '253.0', '']
['11-18-2014 7:50:31', 'AM 1', '**', '104.0', '', '']
['11-18-2014 3:48:43', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '781.0']
['11-19-2014 12:30:36', 'AM 1', '**', '', '260.0', '']
['11-19-2014 8:40:26', 'AM 1', '**', '102.0', '', '']
['11-19-2014 3:47:45', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '803.0']
['11-20-2014 12:28:40', 'AM 1', '**', '', '243.0', '']
['11-20-2014 7:53:38', 'AM 1', '**', '107.0', '', '']
['11-20-2014 3:43:55', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '787.0']
['11-21-2014 1:03:45', 'AM 0', 'PS', '', '245.0', '']
['11-21-2014 7:52:55', 'AM 1', '**', '101.0', '', '']
['11-21-2014 3:44:09', 'PM 1', '**', '', '', '789.0']
['11-22-2014 12:37:26', 'AM 1', '**', '', '250.0', '']
['11-22-2014 7:49:55', 'AM 1', '**', '103.0', '', '']
```

(While it would be more typical to group the AM/PM with the time, I'm trying to follow the description of desired output)

Comment: Ended up using this one.  Works perfectly with everything I've thrown at it so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say how reliable this is in a production environment, but it works on the example data.

Given:

```
txt='''\
Date              Run    By           Level 1        Level 2        Level 3        Level 4        Level 5        Level 6        Level 7        Level 8        Level 9


11-15-2014 12:27:43 AM 1    **                          259.0                                                                                                         
11-15-2014 7:47:09 AM 1    **            98.0                                                                                                                        
11-15-2014 3:45:07 PM 1    **                                         785.0                                                                                          
11-16-2014 12:27:43 AM 1    **                          245.0                                                                                                         
11-16-2014 7:51:36 AM 1    **            96.0                                                                                                                        
11-16-2014 3:43:12 PM 1    **                                         788.0                                                                                          
11-17-2014 12:27:43 AM 1    **                          248.0                                                                                                         
11-17-2014 7:51:21 AM 1    **           104.0                                                                                                                        
11-17-2014 12:45:57 PM 1    **            97.0          257.0          793.0                                                                                          
11-17-2014 3:46:33 PM 1    **                                         792.0                                                                                          
11-18-2014 12:32:31 AM 1    **                          253.0                                                                                                         
11-18-2014 7:50:31 AM 1    **           104.0                                                                                                                        
11-18-2014 3:48:43 PM 1    **                                         781.0                                                                                          
11-19-2014 12:30:36 AM 1    **                          260.0                                                                                                         
11-19-2014 8:40:26 AM 1    **           102.0                                                                                                                        
11-19-2014 3:47:45 PM 1    **                                         803.0                                                                                          
11-20-2014 12:28:40 AM 1    **                          243.0                                                                                                         
11-20-2014 7:53:38 AM 1    **           107.0                                                                                                                        
11-20-2014 3:43:55 PM 1    **                                         787.0                                                                                          
11-21-2014 1:03:45 AM 0    PS                          245.0                                                                                                         
11-21-2014 7:52:55 AM 1    **           101.0                                                                                                                        
11-21-2014 3:44:09 PM 1    **                                         789.0                                                                                          
11-22-2014 12:37:26 AM 1    **                          250.0                                                                                                         
11-22-2014 7:49:55 AM 1    **           103.0                     '''
```

Try:

```
import re

data=txt.splitlines()
header=data.pop(0)

for line in data:

    m=re.search(r'^([\d\-\s:]+)(AM|PM)\s+(\d)\s+(..)([\s\d\.]+)$', line)
    if m:
        l=[]
        l.append(m.group(1)+m.group(2))
        l.append(m.group(3))
        l.append(m.group(4))
        l.append([e.strip() for e in re.findall(r'(\s{15,16}|\s*\d+\.\d)', m.group(5))])
        print l
```

Prints:

```
['11-15-2014 12:27:43 AM', '1', '**', ['', '259.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-15-2014 7:47:09 AM', '1', '**', ['98.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-15-2014 3:45:07 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '785.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-16-2014 12:27:43 AM', '1', '**', ['', '245.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-16-2014 7:51:36 AM', '1', '**', ['96.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-16-2014 3:43:12 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '788.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-17-2014 12:27:43 AM', '1', '**', ['', '248.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-17-2014 7:51:21 AM', '1', '**', ['104.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-17-2014 12:45:57 PM', '1', '**', ['97.0', '257.0', '793.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-17-2014 3:46:33 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '792.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-18-2014 12:32:31 AM', '1', '**', ['', '253.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-18-2014 7:50:31 AM', '1', '**', ['104.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-18-2014 3:48:43 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '781.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-19-2014 12:30:36 AM', '1', '**', ['', '260.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-19-2014 8:40:26 AM', '1', '**', ['102.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-19-2014 3:47:45 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '803.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-20-2014 12:28:40 AM', '1', '**', ['', '243.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-20-2014 7:53:38 AM', '1', '**', ['107.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-20-2014 3:43:55 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '787.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-21-2014 1:03:45 AM', '0', 'PS', ['', '245.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-21-2014 7:52:55 AM', '1', '**', ['101.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-21-2014 3:44:09 PM', '1', '**', ['', '', '789.0', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-22-2014 12:37:26 AM', '1', '**', ['', '250.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
['11-22-2014 7:49:55 AM', '1', '**', ['103.0', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `tsv` format, or **t**ab **s**eparated **v**alues. Try splitting lines on tabs:

```
for line in f:
    print line.split('\t')
```

If this is the case, you can use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), setting tab as the separator.

### Edit:

OP confirms this isn't a tsv. This is my suggestion:

```
headers = None
for line in input_file:
    splits = line.split('    ')
    if headers:
        print zip(headers, [v.strip() for v in splitter.split(line)])
        continue
    headers = splits
```

Comment: Sadly it is not delimited with tabs, those are spaces as shown.

Comment: @Minnow removed regex. Using four spaces as split criteria seems to do the trick.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, but `NameError: name 'headers' is not defined.`

Comment: @Minnow Fixed. simply add `headers = None`, it's just to keep the headers. Use `csv` module to do this if it's possible to set the separator to four spaces.

Comment: The levels are aligned properly. e.g. top row of data, level 2=259.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `re.split()`, but instead `re.findall()` with something like `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s+(\d{,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(\wM \d)\s+\*\*\s{10,15}([0-9.]*)\s{10,15}([0-9.]*)\s{10,15}([0-9.]*)`.

I recognize this is dirty, but since this doesn't seem to be a fixed length of spaces as delimiters, this might do the trick. Will cease to work if the numbers get large.